# Show that $P(A\triangle B)=P(A)+P(B)–2P(A\cap B)$

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to show that $P(A\triangle B)=P(A)+P(B)–2P(A\cap B)$. Knowing that $A\triangle B=(A\cap B^{c})\cup(A^{c} \cap B)$.

So, what I did was this:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
P(A\triangle B)&=P(A)+P(B)–2P(A\cap B)\\
P((A\cap B^{c})\cup(A^{c} \cap B))&= P(A)+P(B)–2P(A\cap B)\\
P(A\cap B^{c})+P(A^{c}\cap B)-P((A\cap B^{c})\cap(A\cap B^{c}))&=P(A)+P(B)–2P(A\cap B)\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

And the truth is, I got stuck there. I thought I'd solve it assuming that they were independent events but I don't know if I'm doing it right.  I would appreciate your help and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Because $$P(A\Delta B)=P\left((A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)\right)=$$
$$=P\left((A\setminus(A\cap B))\cup(B\setminus(A\cap B))\right)=$$
$$=P\left((A\setminus(A\cap B)))+P(B\setminus(A\cap B))\right)=$$
$$=P(A)-P(A\cap B)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)=P(A)+P(B)-2P(A\cap B).$$

Comment: Thank you. It was very clear.

Comment: @Javier Fernando Vivas Camargo You are welcome!

Comment: Why is $P(A \setminus B) = P(A \cap B)$ or what am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @CormJack It was typo. I fixed. Thank you!

Comment: No problem! Here is a question about proof by induction / ODE's maybe you will find interesting :) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4662496/general-solution-to-secular-terms-in-ode-system-inductive-proof

Answer (score 1):

Using the fact that: $$P(K \cup R) = P(K) + P(R) - P( K \cap R)$$

and substituting : $K = A \cap B^c$ and $R = A^c \cap B$ we get:

$$P ( A \triangle B) = P(A \cap B^c) + P(A^c \cap B) - P((A \cap B^c)  \cap (A^c \cap B)) $$

$$= P (A \setminus B) + P(B \setminus A) - P( \emptyset) = P(A) - P(A \cap B) + P(B) - P(A \cap B) = \\
 P(A) + P(B) - 2P(A \cap B)$$

Recall that $P(A \setminus B) = P(A) - P(A \cap B)$ ( I will leave the proof to you... for more information see: [Proof of Probability of Set Difference](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2063036/proof-of-probability-of-set-difference))

Comment: The propriety of $P(A - B) =P(A)-P(A\cap B)$ really helped. I even did the proof. So, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Note: $(A \cap B) \subseteq (A \cup B) \implies P((A \cup B) \setminus (A \cap B)) = P(A\cup B) - P(A \cap B)$

$P(A ∆ B) = P(A \cup B) \cap (A \cap B)^c = P((A \cup B) \setminus (A \cap B)) = P(A\cup B) - P(A \cap B) = P(A) + P(B) - 2P(A \cap B)$